# Best way to aggregate data from NDB datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a `StatisticStore` model defined as:

```
class StatisticStore(ndb.Model):
  user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
  created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  kind = ndb.StringProperty()
  properties = ndb.PickleProperty()

  @classmethod
  def top_links(cls, user, start_date, end_date):
    '''
    returns the user's top links for the given date range
    e.g.
    {'http://stackoverflow.com': 30,
     'http://google.com': 10,
     'http://yahoo.com': 15}
    '''
    stats = cls.query(
      cls.user == user.key,
      cls.created >= start_date,
      cls.created <= end_date,
      cls.kind == 'link_visited'
    )
    links_dict = {}
    # generate links_dict from stats
    # keys are from the 'properties' property
    return links_dict
```

I want to have an `AggregateStatisticStore` model which stores the aggregate of `StatisticStore` per day. It could be generated once a day. Something like:

```
class AggregateStatisticStore(ndb.Model):
  user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
  date = ndb.DateProperty()
  kinds_count = ndb.PickleProperty()
  top_links = ndb.PickleProperty()
```

So that the following would be true:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 22, 0, 0, 0)
end = datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 22, 23, 59, 59)

aug22stats = StatisticStore.query(
  StatisticStore.user == user,
  StatisticStore.kind == 'link_visited',
  StatisticStore.created >= start,
  StatisticStore.created <= end
).count()
aug22toplinks = StatisticStore.top_links(user, start, end)

aggregated_aug22stats = AggregateStatisticStore.query(
  AggregateStatisticStore.user == user,
  AggregateStatisticStore.date == start.date()
)

aug22stats == aggregated_aug22stats.kinds_count['link_visited']
aug22toplinks == aggregated_aug22stats.top_links
```

I was thinking of just running a cronjob with the taskqueue API. The task would generate the `AggregateStatisticStore` of each day. But I was worried it might run into memory issues? Seeing as `StatisticStore` could have a lot of records per user.

Also, the `top_links` property kind of complicates things a bit. I'm not sure yet if having a property for it in the aggregate model is the best way. Any suggestion for that property would be great.

Ultimately I only want to have a record for `StatisticStore` up to only ~30 days ago. If the record is older than 30 days, it should be aggregated (and then deleted). To save on space and to improve query times for visualization.

**EDIT:** How about every time a `StatisticStore` is recorded, it creates/updates the appropriate `AggregateStatisticStore` record. That way, all the cronjob has to do is cleanup. Thoughts?

Comment: have you looked into the mapreduce api?  Updating AgregateStatisticStore when you update a StatistcStore is probably a better idea though.  You probably want to shard AgregateStatisticStore though, but that may depend on your perf requirements.  If the StatisticStore aren't updated frequently for a given user, you might not need to shard it.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at mapreduce, but I'm having a hard time grokking it.  What do you mean by "sharding" AggregateStatisticStore?

Comment: @john2x I thought you can't filter more than one property in the query? Does your query works?

Comment: @Ervald yes, you filter more than one property in the query, provided you only use the equality filter and/or use an inequality filter on only one property. What you can't do is use inequality filters (e.g. !=, <, >, etc.) on different properties.

Comment: @john2x that makes more sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, mapreduce would be good for this. Alternatively you could run your cron job using a "backend" (now module) instance. This may alleviate the memory concern and job length issues.

Another approach might be to move the aggregation to write time. Since this is per user, you may find that you eliminate a lot of work that way.
If AggregateStatisticStore is per day, you might want to use something other than DateProperty for date. DateProperty would work of course, but I find it easier to use IntegerProperty for this kind of thing where the int is just "day since some time".

Comment: By "move the aggregation to write time", do you mean something like my EDIT? Thanks, good point about the DateProperty.

Comment: By write time, I mean when a user adds a link, votes on a link, or whatever action they take that makes it a "top link". So as they do this, you might create a task for example that updates the aggregate. Again this would be instead of using cron for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat related to aggregating data:

Change `StatisticStore` and `AggregateStatisticStore` to have `user.key` as their parent.  This means removing `user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)` from each model, creating each one with `parent = user.key` and using `parent = user.key` in the `query()`s.  NDB is good at aggregating data with the same parent.

Answer (score 0):

If the `AggregateStatisticScore`s are independent of each other, there's no need to use MapReduce.  If you can run a loop for each user, just run a taskqueue process for each one and write a single record.  It's effectively just the "map" phase.

If you can break it down even further into more parallel tasks, then create even more taskqueue processes.  "Parallelize" it!